# How can i get color of the cell if it's haven't got value? (NPOI)

Tags: c#, npoi

I have a task to read some big excel.XLSX file and do something with it in my program. For this I chose the NPOI library, it's mostly working fine, except the cases when I have to read empty cells. The point is, that my excel file contains big blocks of cells that have the same color, sometimes these cells have values, but most of the time - don't. When a color cell contains a value, it's okay, I just can use something like that `ICell cell = sheet.GetRow(0).GetCell(0).CellStyle`. But when cell hasn't got any value, the same string `ICell cell = sheet.GetRow(0).GetCell(0).CellStyle` get "Reference not set to an instance of an object" exception. [Situation looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTkyI.png) What can I do in this case?

Comment: According to [this page](https://trumpexcel.com/highlight-blank-cells-in-excel/), it should work if you use a *selection.*

Answer (score 0):

[Here have some structure about the type](http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents)

In the link, there is a type name "CellType.BLANK".
Maybe you could try to use a condition to get cell.getCellType(), and then change what you want?

Hope if it could help you.